# Prove that $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $g$: $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $g({1})=0$. Define $f_n(x)= x^{n}{g(x)}$.

Prove that $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: Could you tell me where you found this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $g$ is continuous with $g(1) = 0$, there exists a $\delta$, $0 < \delta < 1$ such that for all $x$, $1 - \delta < x \le 1$ implies $|g(x)| < \varepsilon$. Let $N$ be a positive integer greater than $\log(\varepsilon)/\log(1 - \delta)$. If $n\ge N$, then

1.$|f_n(x)| \le (1 - \delta)^n < \varepsilon$ if $x\in [0, 1 - \delta]$.

2.$|f_n(x)| \le |g(x)| < \varepsilon$ if $x\in (1 - \delta, 1)$.

3.$|f_n(x)| = 0 < \varepsilon$ if $x = 1$.

Hence, $|f_n(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and $x\in [0,1]$. Consequently, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

First, if $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, then there is nothing to prove. Now, because the function $g$ is continuous, then it sends compact set to compact set, so $g([0,1])$ is compact, hence its bounded; from this (and from the fact that $g(1)=0$) it follows that for every $x\in [0,1]$, $lim_{n} f_n(x)=0$. Hence, $f_n$ converge pointwise to the zero function. 
Now, product of continuous functions is continuous, hence $|x^n g(x)|$ is continuous; by the extreme value theorem $|x^n g(x)|$ must attain a maximum at some point $a\in (0,1)$ (We can assume $a$ different from $0$ and $1$, because otherwise g would be trivial), then $sup_{ x\in [0,1]} |x^n g(x)|= |a^ng(a)|$. If you take the limit, then you have the uniform convergence.

Comment: Why is $a$ independent of $n$?

Comment: I'm sorry, a is not indipendent from n. There is a sequence of $a_n$, one for each n; but, because for $m<n$, i have $|x^m g(x)|\le |x^n g(x)|$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, then $|a_n^ng(a_n)|\le |a_1^n g(a_1)|$. Now, i can take the limit.

Comment: And why is $|a_n^n g(a_n)| \leq |a_1^n g(a_1)|$? It seems to me you are using some monotonicity of $g$...

Comment: You are right, that's not true in general. what i have, it is that, $|a_m^mg(a_m)|\leq |a_m^ng(a_m)|\leq |a_n^ng(a_n)|$ for $m>n$ (in the previous, there is a misprint, $m<n$ should be $m>n$). But this is not sufficient for the uniform convergence.

Comment: Sorry if i write again, but i want to be sure to have understand. Let $\beta:=sup_n(a_n)$. If $\beta=1$, then, fix an $m$. For every $\varepsilon>0$, because of the continuity of $|x^m g(x)|$, there exist a $\delta>0$, such that, for every $x\in (1-\delta,1)$, $|x^m g(x)|<\varepsilon$. But, there exist, also, an $m_0$ such that, for every $n>m_0$ : $a_n \in (1-\delta,1)$. Taking, $n>max(m_0,m)$ i have: $|a_n^ng(a_n)|\leq |a_n^mg(a_m)|\leq \varepsilon. If $\beta\in (0,1)$, then $ a_m^m< \beta^m $ for every $m$.

Comment: If $K:= max(|g(x)|$, then for every $n$: $|a_n^ng(a_n)|\leq a_n^nK \leq \beta^nK$. Taking the limit, i have the result. I hope this is correct. @Siminore, thank you very much for your attention.